# How to set a maximum boundary using the set_y2_axis function with XLSXWRITER?

Tags: python, charts, xlsxwriter

It seems that it is currently not possible to set a maximum boundary using the function `set_y2_axis()` with XLSXWriter. It is working properly for `set_y_axis()`.

In the below example, the y-axis will be bounded to 3.5 but the y-axis will not be bounded to 100:

```
column_chart.set_y_axis({'name': 'Frequency (%)',
                         'max': 3.5,
                         })
column_chart.set_y2_axis({'name': 'Cummulative Frequency (%)',
                          'max': 100.0,
                          })
```

In the [official documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/chart.html), it is stated that for `set_y2_axis`:
*"The properties that can be set are the same as for set_x_axis, see above."*
And max and min values aren't supported by Excel for category axes like the x-axis in a line chart ([corresponding issue on github](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/194)).
However, it is possible to set a maximum boundary for a secondary y-axis in Excel...

[image]

Could you please tell me what I missed or what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance,

Romain

EDIT:

My error was that I was applying the `set_y2_axis()` on the wrong chart. I was applying on the "final" combined `column_chart` but it should be applied on the `line_chart` before calling `combine()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Here is a simple working example that sets the maximum for the secondary axis to 10:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('chart_secondary_axis.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Write some data.
data = [
    [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    [10, 40, 50, 20, 10, 50],
]

worksheet.write_column('A1', data[0])
worksheet.write_column('B1', data[1])

# Create the chart.
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})

chart.add_series({
    'values': '=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$6',
    'y2_axis': 1,
})

chart.add_series({
    'values': '=Sheet1!$B$1:$B$6',

})

chart.set_y2_axis({'max': 10})

worksheet.insert_chart('D2', chart)

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]